# Send and download data with "Background Runner" in CapacitorJS

Tags: capacitor

I am planning to use capacitorJS and the background-runner pluging.

My need is :

- while the application is running in foreground and offline, it will locally save some datas (in files, or whatever but locally)
- when the application is in background, and if the phone is online, it will read and send the content of the file(s) to a remote server, and save the response in another file.

I see exemples about notifications and CapacitorKV calls, but nothing about the file access. The data to save will count in some kilos, so I guess CapacitorKV is out of question.

Is it possible ?

Thanks